# How to disable django REST framework docs page

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am currently using Django REST framework and it works very well for me. The problem is that the API documentation page is public in production and I would like it to only be seen in development (localhost) or by administrators users.
This is my `urls.py`:

```
schema_view = get_schema_view(title='My API')
router = DefaultRouter()
# router.register(...) 

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^docs/', include_docs_urls(title='My API service')),
    url(r'^schema/$', schema_view),
]
```

PS: I'm using the version 3.9.2

Comment: Please show us how your `urls.py` looks now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always check for the `DEBUG` value and do stuff if it is set (which is set to `True` in development mode). For example:

```
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^schema/$', schema_view),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += [
        url(r'^docs/', include_docs_urls(title='My API service'))
    ]
```